# How to combine two nested for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop

So I have this code for checking tic tac toe winner in row and in column:

```
for row in range(rows):
    symbols_in_row = 0
    for column in range(columns):
        if grid[row][column] == player_symbol:
            symbols_in_row += 1
            if symbols_in_row == winning_line:
                return True
        else:
            symbols_in_row = 0

for column in range(columns):
    symbols_in_column = 0
    for row in range(rows):
        if grid[row][column] == player_symbol:
            symbols_in_column += 1
            if symbols_in_column == winning_line:
                return True
        else:
            symbols_in_column = 0
```

How can I do it in one loop?

Comment: There's currently not enough information in your question to answer it.  Regardless and assuming it's even possible, why would you want to do this as it likely to require some very convoluted code.

Comment: Which 2 of these 4 loops are you talking about? What benefit do you see in combining them?

Comment: What's the size of your Tic Tac Toe? Is it ordinary 3x3?

Comment: @ThomasWeller No it is optional. From user input.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use NumPy, you can use its sum methods to identify if you have won. Take player1 as 1, player2 as -1, and no entry as 0. If the sum of a row, column, or diagonal is +3 or -3 a player has won.

```py
    import numpy as np
    
    matrix = np.zeros([3,3])
    
    row_sum = matrix.sum(axis = 1)
    col_sum = matrix.sum(axis = 0)
    diag1_sum = np.trace(matrix)
    diag2_sum = np.trace(np.flip(matrix, axis=1))

    for i in [row_sum, col_sum, diag1_sum, diag2_sum]:
        if(3 in i or -3 in i): ## Checking which one has one is upto you
            print("victory")
```